# "List indices must be integers or slices, not list" when clipping unwanted min valuable from list with one liner

Tags: python, list-comprehension, one-liner

```
mlist = [["Rachel", -50],["Mawer", -50],["Sheen",-50],["Shaheen",51]]
list1 = []

x = sorted(mlist, key = lambda x : x[1])
print(x[1])

x = [x for x in x if x[x][1] != x[0][1]]
print(x)

def over1():
    for i in range(4):
        if x[i][1] == x[0][1]:
            list1.append(x[i][0])
        
    list1.sort()
    print(*list1, sep="\n")

over1()
```

I am trying to delete all variables which have minimum of the second element of each value in the list and I wanted to make it happen with using `x`. (`print(x)` for control purposes)

In the line `x = [x for x in x if x[x][1] != x[0][1]]` compiler gives me the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not list".

Is it possible with using `x` only and where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you explain what a "min second value" is? Also, what is the expected result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: -50 is the min value and i wanted to remove all variables contains -50 
expected return is ["Shaheen", 51]

Comment: You are using `x` for two different entities, which causes confusion. Try `x = [u for u in x if u[1] != x[0][1]]`.

Comment: its working now with your suggestions but why u[1] is working why its not u[u][1] and is it possible with using x ?

Comment: When you have `[u for u in x]`,  `u` is a single element `x`. That is to say, it is a list, where the first instance of `u` is `["Rachel", -50]`.  Another problem is in your `over1()` function, where you hard coded in a range of 4 but you are reducing the list to a size of 1 earlier in the routine.  Instead of hardcoding, use `range(len(x))`.  Even better if you pass the list into the function instead of relying in the global variable scope.

Comment: Thank you for over1 reccomendation but i understand why is problem but can you explain why u[1] (which ["Rachel", -50]) can compare with x[0][1] (which just integer -50). This point i don't understand

Comment: `u` represents a complete single element of `x`, which is a list, such as `["Rachel", -50] or `["Mawer", -50]`.  Then `u[0]` = `"Rachael"` and `u[1]` = `-50`.     
  Another way of writing it, if we say `sorted_list = x`,  might be `reduced_list = [element for element in sorted_list if element[1] != sorted_list[0][1]]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a complete one-liner would be considered good programming, but I managed to do this in 2 lines by using list comprehension. I first find the minimum value and then use that to produce a resultant list that does not contain the minimum value:

```py
mlist = [['Rachel', -50], ['Mawer', -50], ['Sheen', -50], ['Shaheen', 51]]

min_val = min([a[1] for a in mlist])
x = [a for a in mlist if a[1] != min_val]

print(*x, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
['Shaheen', 51]
```

Comment: How a[1] (which ["Rachel", -50] and we want to compare second property of the item) can compare with min_val (which just integer -50). Can you elaborate for me please?

Comment: @Mindtrip `a` is each element in `mlist` (`['Rachel', -50]`, `['Mawer', -50]`, ...). `a[1]` would be the 2nd element in each `a` (`-51`, `-51`, ...). So, comparing `a[1]` to `min_val` is simply comparing the integer value of each sublist with the minimum integer value we found.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [x for x in x if x[x][1] != x[0][1]]
```

First of: this code line is a little hard to read.
Second: you're basically trying to iterste over an a list of x, and then assign value of x[0] to it in

```
for x in x
```

Third: you iterating over list of lists, so you cant use x[x] because x is equal to ["Rachel": -50].
Fourth: python is interpreter, not compiler, you may want to keep that in mind for later learning of the language